# I want to access this order id which is retrieved from database but it generates an error

Tags: c#

I want to access this order id which is retrieved from database but it generates an error.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
{
    Label lblorderid = (Label)item.FindControl("lblorderid");
    if (lblorderid != null)
    {
        Label lblproduct = (Label)item.FindControl("lblproduct");
        str = "SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_product where order_id="+ lblorderid.Text +" ";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, cn);
        object count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (count != null)
        {
            lblproduct.Text += count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near "="

Comment: but if i write like this then it work

Comment: foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            Label lblorderid = (Label)item.FindControl("lblorderid");
            if (lblorderid != null)
            {
                Label lblproduct = (Label)item.FindControl("lblproduct");
                str = "SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_product where order_id='9'";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(str, cn);
                object count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (count != null)
                {
                    lblproduct.Text += count.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Sounds like the lblorderid.text isn't the value you think it is. Have you checked for trailing spaces? Have you tried debugging?

Comment: @sr28 what you mean trailing space ? can u explain me what exactly you try to say

Comment: As you are taking the value from a textbox a space could be after (or before) the value and therefore you'd be inputting "9 " for example into your query. However, it would be better to parameterise your query as per S.Akbari suggested. You should also confirm the input is in fact an int (use int.Parse).

Answer (score 1):

You missed single quote after `order_id=` it should be like this:

```
str = "SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_product where order_id= '"+ lblorderid.Text +"'";
```

But you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
str = "SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_product where order_id= @orderid";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderid", lblorderid.Text);
```

Comment: i mean yaaaa there is no error but count operation is not working

Comment: my order_id datatype is int

Comment: @NikitaJadav...What do you mean by  count operation doesn't work exactly?

Comment: Sorry Sir but still not working

Comment: i mena if i write like  first suggestion it'll not generate an error but the no.of product it not displayed

Comment: sir the problem is if i m using first solution it will not count the no.of product because where condition is not satisfied here bcoz my order_id is integer and i am converting it into the string by writing this             str = "SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_product where order_id= '"+ lblorderid.Text +"'";

Comment: @NikitaJadav - assuming you've made the suggestions above, have you tried debugging to confirm the value of lblorderid?

Comment: @sr28 Sorry Sir what u mean?

Comment: @NikitaJadav - are you using Visual Studio? If so, which version?

Comment: @sr28 Visual Studio 2012

Comment: @NikitaJadav - make sure you're build is set to 'Debug'. Click in the grey margin on the left hand side to set a breakpoint on 'str = ....'. Run your code by hitting F5 and it should hit the breakpoint. Hover over lblorderid.text and confirm the value it has.

Comment: @sr28 still not work no changes at all.........i mean yaaa lblorderid.text has value

Answer (score 0):

Further to my comments here is what I think you should change your code to:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
{
    Label lblorderid = (Label)item.FindControl("lblorderid");
    int orderId;
    if (lblorderid != null && int.TryParse(lblorderid.Text, out orderId))
    {
        Label lblproduct = (Label)item.FindControl("lblproduct");
        str = "SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_product where order_id= @orderid";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderid", orderId);
        int count = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (count != null)
        {
            lblproduct.Text += count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cn.Open();
        str = "select * from tbl_order";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(str, cn);
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        Repeater1.DataSource = ds;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
        {
            Label lblorderid = (Label)item.FindControl("lblorderid");
            if (lblorderid != null)
            {
                Label lblproduct = (Label)item.FindControl("lblproduct");
                str = "SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl_product where order_id='"+ lblorderid.Text+"'";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(str, cn);
                int count = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                if (count != null)
                {
                    lblproduct.Text += count.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        cn.Close();
```

Comment: Not sure I understand why you've posted this? Are you saying this code is now working? What change did you make if it is?

Comment: i am posting this original code and them i am try to implement your suggested new code but still not display total number of product ...

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet? If not, then you really need to do so. First to identify that the orderId is in fact an int, and second that it returns a count. If it doesn't then you will never see anything in lblproduct.Text. On a side note, you shouldn't post your original code (that's not working) as an answer.